# How to use WIX's SetDirectory correctly

Tags: wix

I have a fragment that handles the installation location for my app, however I want to install to a custom location (C:\PtecMonitor) vs Program Files(x86)....

```
<Fragment>
   <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
       <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
         <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="PtecMonitor" />
       </Directory>
     <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
       <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="Ptec Share Monitor"/>
     </Directory>
   </Directory>
   <SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Name="[WindowsVolume]" />
</Fragment>
```

This throws up an error "**The SetDirectory/@Value attribute was not found; it is required.**"

Where is SetDirectory supposed to be set in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<SetDirectory />` Does not have a Attribute called "**Name**" you Probably want to set "**Value**" instead.
Please see the Documentation for more information
https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setdirectory.html

Comment: Evidently I need to vet some examples.... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SetProperty and SetDirectory are syntactical sugar to simplify authoring MSI Type 51 (Set Property ) and Type 35 ( Set Directory ) custom actions.  In general type 51 should be scheduled prior to costing and type 35 should be scheduled after costing.